# Sumo select remove all indexes and reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, reset, sumoselect.js

I have integrated [Sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/). select it for cascading state and city dropdown.

Initially City drop is blank. On section of States, it adds Options under City dropdown.

Question is how to remove all options of City dropdown, if someone de-selects all the selected states?
There is only provision to remove options using index. So how to remove all the options at one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all indexes in num variable.

```
var num = $('option').length;

for(var i=num; i>=1; i--)
{
   $('.SlectBox')[0].sumo.remove(i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can delete all the HTML of the **select** element linked to SumoSelect and then reload the SumoSelect of that element. For example:

```
$('#MySelect').html('');
$('#MySelect')[0].sumo.reload();
```

Comment: after hours of hunting, this helped. Sumo Select documentation should really be updated.